# Why is Ubuntu 14.10 not yet available at the Ubuntu Official Site?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 14.10, ubuntu-website

Today is the official release date for Ubuntu 14.10. It is now past 6:30 pm in my country and past 5:30 pm in Britain where the main server is located I suppose? 
Yet Ubuntu 14.10 is not available at the main page. However it seems that it is available at torrent sites of Ubuntu. It is not available for upgrade either. What is going on?

Comment: Servers aren't magic. It takes time to update everything. It will happen soon; just be patient.

Comment: It is not out yet.

Comment: There are images ready in http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.10/. I don't know whether they're final though.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the new release:
http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.10/
Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

You can download/update to 14.10 - just read [the release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UtopicUnicorn/ReleaseNotes).

It will likely take time to update the main site and other areas. Various pages (such as [the download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), [the upgrade tutorial](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade), [the shop](http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17), and [the official flavours links](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UtopicUnicorn/ReleaseNotes#Official_flavours)) need to be updated - this will likely be finished soon.