# When will Ubuntu 18.04 release and at what time?

Tags: release-management

I heard that April 26 will be the day Ubuntu 18.04 is going to be releasing its stable version.

Is it possible to know **in advance** at what time?

Comment: @andrew.46 `daily-live` is not the final release (by definition).

Comment: We are busy testing (and if necessary, the developers are squashing some remaining bugs). Please wait for some more hours (or days if a new showstopping bug appears) . [Ubuntu Development version / How to participate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018033/ubuntu-development-version-how-to-participate)

Comment: Why does it matter? The daily-live is up to date and usable. Might be some bugs here and there but that does not mean those will affect you. I am on 18.04 and have been for a month already.

Comment: When it is ready? Soon™! Or in other words when its there it is there, same question we get every time a new release is coming and the same answers apply here too.

Comment: This question is important in that I need to stop clicking `18.04` bugs as off-topic due to being in development phase.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix definitively today you can stop closing 18.04 questions, the release will happen for sure today as there was no change in release schedule announced.

Comment: @Videonauth I retracted my one close vote today but I see someone already voted along: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028359/ubuntu-18-04-boot-issues For some reason the date April 29 was stuck in the back of my mind.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Yes, I see, but if you look at [the release schedule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseSchedule) it becomes clear, even tho some of the https://wiki.ubuntu.com pages show Bionic still as future, but my hard guess is that they simply need some time to change all and everything.

Comment: IMHO I disagree with the duplicate mark for this question. Here it is asked if it is possible to  know  __in advance__ WHEN (time in the day) it will be released and not where to see if it is already released... Users 3k+ can you vote for reopening? [@Rinzwind maybe you can rethink your vote... I even  fixed the misaligned headers `:-)` ]

Comment: Seems like images are starting to show up.... http://releases.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04/

Comment: Hurray :)  A smooth upgrade from 17.10.  The upgrade site was in place before the ISO was available.

Comment: @Hastur As someone who's been fairly well versed in the releases, it's impossible to get the time of day because that is also variable by where people are on the planet.  Consider also that the answer here *and* the answer on the marked duplicate say the same thing, basically.

Comment: @ThomasWard That comment exits with another question marked as duplicate. I didn't know the present one, BTW  0-before all)  Thanks for the comment. 1) the most voted and accepted answers are 7+ years old and things should change in a so wide period. 2) The answer below gives hints and method to see when the other releases were made 3) I disagree about punctuality: it depends on the period between the freeze and the release moment. If it was not enough it was bad planning. This one(18.04) it is an LTS version,  it exits every 2 years, has a long support time. It should be planned thoughtfully.

Comment: @ThomasWard Just for fun but if I remember well the Ubuntu  10.10 exits the 10 / 10 / '10 at 10:10:10 UTC... (maybe too much `:-)`). 
BTW, IMO, for something that exits each 2 years and remain valid for 5, I think it is possible to plan all in order to finish in advance of a couple of days (or more) and wait for the specific-official date/time. Even a week is 1% of the time between releases

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Each time it is different `:-)`... and unknown in advance (at least until the 18.04).

---

**Update:** [(Thu Apr 26 22:59:59 UTC 2018)](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2018-April/000231.html)
Now it's out. You can start from the [Bionic Beaver](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes) page or from the links below.

One of the most comfortable solution to know when a new release exits, is to [subscribe to the *ubuntu-announce* mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-announce) and wait for a mail. (As you can check there are not so many and it will not *spam* your account).

---

It will appear in the [Bionic Beaver (18.04) page](http://releases.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04/) instead of the beta-2 version, or in the download sections of the Ubuntu site [[d1](https://www.ubuntu.com/download), [d2](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)], or on the [cdimage Ubuntu site](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/18.04/) in the *release* directory (again not the beta-2)...

Nonetheless you may have some hints from the past [[12.04](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04.0/?C=M;O=A), [14.04](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04.0/?C=M;O=A), [16.04](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/16.04.0/?C=M;O=A)],
looking for the 1<sup>st</sup> and last ISO file creation time present in the old-releases Ubuntu site:

<kbd><kbd>**Release**</kbd>    <kbd>**Day**</kbd>       <kbd>**1<sup>st</sup> ISO file**</kbd>       <kbd>**Last ISO file**</kbd>           <kbd>**Last FILE**</kbd>        

 <kbd>12.04 LTS</kbd>  <kbd>**26**<sup>th</sup></kbd>  <kbd>'12 Apr 23 12:27</kbd>  <kbd>'12 Apr 25 16:13</kbd>  <kbd>2012-04-**26 09:51**</kbd>

 <kbd>14.04 LTS</kbd>  <kbd>**17**<sup>th</sup></kbd>  <kbd>'14 Apr 16 21:13</kbd>  <kbd>'14 Apr 17 01:37</kbd>  <kbd>2014-04-**17 15:00**</kbd>

 <kbd>16.04 LTS</kbd>  <kbd>**21**<sup>st</sup></kbd>  <kbd>'16 Apr 20 22:30</kbd>  <kbd>'16 Apr 20 23:38</kbd>  <kbd>2016-04-**21 11:08**</kbd></kbd>

Of course you have to search for the first release (the one without `.1`, `.2`, ...).

For a somehow more *"trusted"* version (suggested as automatic update from the previous LTS) you should usually wait until the `.1` release (usually in July-August; this time it is [scheduled for July 26](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseSchedule).

We should [mind the timezone](https://askubuntu.com/q/1028334/196535) and that we should even [wait until the files are uploaded to the various mirrors](https://askubuntu.com/q/540659/196535).

Answer (score 9):

According to [this](https://fossbytes.com/ubuntu-18-04-not-released-yet/), this is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntukylin/+bug/1767067) that delayed the release of Ubuntu momentarily.

> About seven hours ago, the development team found a bug and it’s
>   currently being fixed. Apparently, Bug #1767067 affects the live
>   session options in Ubuntu, Ubuntu Kylin, Ubuntu Budgie, and Ubuntu
>   MATE flavors. As per the latest update, the team is working hard to
>   fix the bug and testing the release. (Update: The team has fixed the
>   bug and the official release will be out anytime soon).