# Ubuntu 18.04 boot issues

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, 18.04

I upgraded my OS to Ubuntu 18.04 from Ubuntu 17.10 today after it was released.

The boot stops at a black screen saying nothing just one line, something about my SSD being loaded. The only way to start the OS is removing all the `nvidia` packages and replacing `quiet splash` by `nomodeset` in boot options on grub.

I need to know why this works and how do I fix the problem so that I don't have to do this all the time and start using my Nvidia drivers.

I have `nvidia-390` driver installed

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/747314/is-nomodeset-still-required

Comment: To close voters: according to release schedule of bionic the release date is today, so closing as off topic because of developtment version not applies anymore! See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseSchedule

Comment: I am not talking about the development version here. I upgraded my ubuntu today after the final version was released on the update channel of ubuntu.  Am I not getting something correct, in that case please clarify

Comment: Yeah, same problem here, I can't get xorg to work with gdm, and nvidia-390 to work with wayland. I somehow ended up with wayland as default. Either nvidia drivers are broken af, or xorg is broken or both. Upgrade for me was a disaster.

Comment: @akabhirav No, my comment was simply, to prevent your question getting closed as off topic. I just saw seconds after you posted it that it accumulated close votes.

Comment: Now to the matter at hand, have you tried to boot into the maintenance mode and checked if you can boot if you remove the Nvidia driver? Are you using the driver from the graphic-drivers-ppa or the one delivered with 18.04?

Comment: An alternative is to 1. 'Try Ubuntu', when booted from a USB pendrive cloned from the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS iso file; 2. If it works (with `nomodeset`), consider backing up your home directory `/home` (of your installed system) to another drive. The intention is to use it later on; 3. Install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS alongside your current system or in an external drive (for example in a fast USB 3 pendrive) ; 4. If it works, replace your current system with a fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, where you create a separate home partition and use your old `/home` from the backup.

Comment: thank you both, It actually worked and it did startup, but alas reinstalling can't be really the answer. I did reinstall but others might find it very laborious. I keep my files organized because I format a lot, just to keep experimenting with my system

Comment: I have one production operating system, that I keep in a stable state, and do the experimenting in other [separate] operating systems. It is best to run these systems in a different computer or in a virtual machine, but it is also possible to run them alongside the production operating system (dual boot or multi boot).

Comment: Was this ever solved? What's the status of your system now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This helped me:

- Open Terminal and run:

  ```
  sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
  ```
- change GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=...... to:

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.modeset=0"
  ```
- Delete any extras like `nomodeset`,`acpi=off`,etc and after that update grub:

  ```
  sudo update-grub
  ```
- Restart.

Of course its better to first test this from `grub` (while rebooting), editing the starting line (Ubuntu-line) with the <kbd>e</kbd>-key.